# Modulo operation, why does 4 % 12 give the number 4?

Tags: java, math

How does dividing 4 by 12 return a remainder of 4? I know that 12%4 = 0, but what if it is reversed?

Comment: Simple math, 12 doesnt divide into 4 so gives remainder of 4

Comment: The modulus operator is not commutative.

Comment: What else should it give?

Comment: @Reimeus You meant probably that 4 does not divide into 12. No?

Comment: @user3195991 Welcome back, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, to avoid down votes on your questions in the future.

Comment: @peter.petrov no, "12 doesn't divide into 4" is correct.  If we talk about dividing X **by** Y, we're computing X/Y or X%Y; but if we talk about dividing X **into** Y, we're computing Y/X or Y%X.  I'm assuming you're not a native English speaker...

Comment: @ajb No, I am not. That was a useful clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The modulo operator, more or less, just gives you the remainder of the division. So:

12 % 4 = 0 since 12 / 4 = 3 **remainder 0**

Whereas, since 12 doesn't divide 4:

4 % 12 = 4 since 4 / 12 = 0 **remainder 4**

For more information, see the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), or perhaps the [Wolfram article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mod.html).

Answer (score 3):

Dividing 4 by 12 gives 0 with 4 left over.  Hence a remainder of 4.  If the absolute value of the left side of the modulus is less than the absolute value of the right side, the answer will always be the left side.

```
I.e.
4%12=4
4%55=4
87%88=87
```

Comment: Well, I could nitpick and downvote you because -5 is less than 3 but `(-5)%3` isn't -5.  :) :) :)  But I'll be nice just for today.

Comment: Edited to take this into account.  Good catch!

Answer (score 2):

because 12 goes into 4 zero times. Therefore the remainder after subtracting 12 * 0 is 4